# Python - Get custom modules from current file

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of the imported custom modules (modules I created by myself) in my current file but I could not find a proper way to achieve it.

For example:

```
<test.py>
import sys
import foo
import bar
```

I would like to get a list of `[foo, bar]` excluding the `sys` module.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say, that if file located near curent file, or in some subfolder, when it's "our" module, not system one.

For this example, I've created three files: main.py, other.py and another.py, and placed whem into one folder.

The code of main.py is:

```
# os and sys are needed to work
import sys
import os

import shutil
import io
import datetime
import other
import another

def get_my_modules():
    # Get list of modules loaded
    modules = list(sys.modules.keys())

    mymodules = []

    # Get current dir
    curdir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    for m in modules:
        try:
            # if some module's file path located in current folder or in some subfolder
            # lets sey, that it's our self-made module
            path = sys.modules[m].__file__
            if path.startswith(curdir):
                mymodules.append(m)
        except Exception:
        # Exception could happen if module doesn't have any __file__ property
            pass

    # Return list of our moudles
    return mymodules

print(get_my_modules())
```

And this code actually outputs ["other", "another"]

This approach has a problem: If you import module, that somehow located in upper folder, it woudln't be detected.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! However, my modules are not in the same file. What I did for example is: in the same file (test.py) I am finding the current modules modules = inspect.getmembers( sys.modules[__name__], inspect.ismodule ) but I do now know how to distinguish.

Comment: If you know, where does your modules located, you can enhance this function, to check "if module's file in the specified folder", and decide that it's "your" module.

Comment: Also, if you don't have a lot of your own modules, you can add line like "__ mymodule __ = True" in the begining of everyone. So, the function could check, if module have attribute "__ mymodule __" - then is TRULY YOURS module :)